# Extract a string in linux shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Guys i have a string like this:

```
variable='<partyRoleId>12345</partyRoleId>'
```

what i want is to extract the value so the output is 12345.

Note the tag can be in any form:
`<partyRoleId>` or `<ns1:partyRoleId>`

any idea how to get the tag value using grep or sed only?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML parser to extract the value:

```
echo "$variable" | xmllint -xpath '*/text()' -
```

You probably should use it for the whole XML document instead of extracting a single line from it into a variable, anyway.

Comment: i wqnt to used grep or sed only

Comment: @yarabyarab: These tools are not good for parsing XML. Do you know that the element can also be equivalently written as `<partyRoleId><![CDATA[12345]]></partyRoleId>`?

Answer (score 0):

to use only grep, you need regexp to find first closing brackets and cut all digits:

```
echo '<partyRoleId>12345</partyRoleId>'|grep -Po ">\K\d*"
```

-P means PCRE
-o tells to grep to show only matched pattern
and special \K tells to grep cut off everything before this.